# Change default IDE in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

How to tell Unity 3d to open Scripts with Monodevelop?

My system run's :

- Ubuntu 17.10
- MonoDevelop 5.10
- Unity 2017.3.0p2

Usualy, under windows, Unity will open scripts with Visual Studio when double clicked.

I am under linux and to achieve the same thing I have to use Monodevelop.
Everything is working fine but I would like unity to launch Monodevelop to edit the scripts.

Most forum are saying that unity should launch mono to edit script but for some reason my built is not. If I try to open a script within Unity there is just nothing hapening. Its not even asking me how should it open the file.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: While you may have found your solution, note that MonoDevelop  support will be dropped soon. Use this time to switch to another IDE

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Open `Edit -> Preferences`, go to the `External Tools` tab and then choose MonoDevelop from the drop down `External Script Editor` menu:

If your version of Unity did not come with MonoDevelop built in. From the same menu click browse and go to your MonoDevelop Standalone executable.

[image]

Then choose `Browse` and select your MonoDevelop executable.

Comment: Yes I am trying but its not working. I have an option to install monodev but its leading me to a 404 on unity website. Im looking into it still

Comment: Yeah i got it working. I cant use the monoDev built in. I have to specify the location of monoDevelop stand alone. Not from unity folder but the one that i have installed.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and add Browse -> To your stand alone Monodevelop executable So i can accept this as a working The built in one isnt working and the link from unity is even broken.